# T-SQL: Using INSERT INTO & OUTPUT inside CASE clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to assign a new_id to a field inside a CASE clause.

Here is the example:

```
INSERT INTO [table1]
   (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6)
SELECT @someID1, field1_from_table2, @someID2, field2_from_table2, 
 CASE 
  WHEN field3_from_table2 IS NULL 
   THEN INSERT INTO [table3] 
        OUTPUT inserted.some_new_id 
        DEFAULT VALUES
  ELSE field3_from_table2
 END
FROM [table2]
```

The code fragment

```
INSERT INTO [table3] 
OUTPUT inserted.some_new_id 
DEFAULT VALUES
```

works fine when used outside of the CASE clause.

The main problem is that I have to assign a new_id obtained from table3 when the field3_from_table2 I'm trying to insert into table1 IS NULL.
table3 is just an ID dispatcher.

Any idea or workaround to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot have statements inside your `CASE` - it is only designed to **return values** (`WHEN .... THEN (some value here)` )

Comment: @Chorinator, if `field3_from_table2` is `NULL`, is the row to be `INSERT`ed into table1 in your example?

Comment: @Gonsalu No, is not in the example, but it's a pretty simple table. It only contains one column and it's an identity. I use that table only as an Id dispatcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by marc_s, you can't do that using the a case.
You can see the correct case syntax [here](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/39235;pt=39091).

To solve your problem the best solution is to use a [cursor](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/50501;pt=50305).

You can see an code example for a sp with a cursor [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc20020_1251/html/databases/X61512.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `table3` generates sequential integer values, like a `IDENTITY` property with increments of value 1, you can generate those yourself using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), and then `INSERT`ing the generated values into `table3`.

But, since you're generating the values yourself, you must lock `table3` to prevent changes ocurring to it while the statement runs.

Let's set up a test case.

```sql
USE tempdb
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('table1', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE table1;
IF OBJECT_ID('table2', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE table2;
IF OBJECT_ID('table3', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE table3;

CREATE TABLE table1 (
    field1 int,
    field2 int,
    field3 int,
    field4 int,
    field5 int
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    field1_from_table2 int,
    field2_from_table2 int
);

CREATE TABLE table3 (
    field1_from_table3 int IDENTITY(1,1)
);

INSERT INTO table2
VALUES (1000, 2000)
     , (1001, NULL);
GO

-- INSERT 20 records to generate some IDENTITY increments.
INSERT INTO table3 DEFAULT VALUES
GO 20
```

Here's the example code to generate the sequential values.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT table3 ON;
GO

DECLARE @someID1 int = 100
      , @someID2 int = 200;
DECLARE @output table (field4 int, field5 int);

-- Lock table3 exclusively to prevent INSERTs that spoil IDENTITY values.
SELECT TOP(0) 1 FROM table3 WITH (HOLDLOCK, TABLOCKX);

-- INSERT into table1, generating sequential integers
-- and saving the output in @output.
INSERT INTO table1
OUTPUT inserted.field4
     , inserted.field5
  INTO @output(field4, field5)
SELECT @someID1
     , field1_from_table2
     , @someID2
     , field2_from_table2
     , CASE
         WHEN field2_from_table2 IS NOT NULL THEN field2_from_table2
         ELSE (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY field2_from_table2
                                  ORDER BY field2_from_table2))
              + (SELECT MAX(field1_from_table3) FROM table3)
       END
   FROM table2;

-- INSERT generated integer values.
INSERT INTO table3 (field1_from_table3)
SELECT field5
  FROM @output
 WHERE field4 IS NULL;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT table3 OFF;
GO

COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM table1;
SELECT * FROM table2;
SELECT * FROM table3;
```